# How do i get the XYZ coordinates of all the points from point cloud?

Tags: python, open3d

```
import open3d as o3d
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh('myscan.stl')
pcd = mesh.sample_points_uniformly(number_of_points=200000)
```

I have my points on pcd but how do i get all of the points coordinates XYZ?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the points with `np.asarray(pcd.points)`.